# Number of conjugates of x in K a subgroup of G.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, let $K$ be a subgroup of $G$ and $x$ $\epsilon$ $G$. Use the technique that you know to show that the number of distinct conjugates of $x$ by elements of $K$ is $[K : K \bigcap C_G (x)]$.

so my way of answering it was to use the Lemma: For each $x$ $\epsilon$ $G$, the set of conjugates of $x$ has $n$ elements and $n/|G|$, in fact $|G|=[G:C_G (x)]*|C_G (x)|$ and most importantly $n = [G:C_G (x)]$

i used the fact that G is a subgroup of itself and $G\bigcap C_G (x) = C_G (x)$ to entend the proof of the above lemma to some other subgroup $K$...

the proof produces the required result but i am not convinced that i can do what i did above... any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let $K$ act on $G$ by conjugation. Then the set of distinct conjugates of $x$  by elements of $K$ is just the orbit of $x$ under this action. It is a basic fact about group actions that:
$$ |\textrm{orbit of } x| = \frac{|K|}{|\textrm{stabiliser of } x|}.$$

Where the stabiliser of $x$ is the set of elements of $K$ that fix $x$. Fixing $x$ under conjugation, is equivalent to being in $C_G(x)$. So $Stab(x) = K \cap C_G(x)$. Thus,
$$ |\textrm{orbit of } x| = \frac{|K|}{|K \cap C_G(x)|}= [K:K\cap C_G(x)].$$